# Which is more secure: EncryptedSharedPreferences or storing directly in KeyStore?

Tags: android, security, encryption, sharedpreferences, keystore

I'm looking for a secure way to store a shared secret in my Android app.

SharedPreferences is not secure because data is stored unencrypted and can be easily accessed on rooted devices.

I've read about using KeyStore and EncryptedSharedPreferences for secure storage. EncryptedSharedPreferences encrypts data before storing it in SharedPreferences, and the encryption key is stored in KeyStore.

I'm confused about whether I should use EncryptedSharedPreferences or store the shared secret directly in KeyStore. Which approach is more secure and why?

Comment: The Android KeyStore is designed for storing secret keys, so an entry is probably limited in size to a few thousand bytes. While EncryptedSharedPreferences is intended for storing key-value pairs.

Comment: Unless the shared secret is really a crypto key (e.g. an AES key) you won't be able to store it directly in AndroidKeyStore as this store can only be used with crypto keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyStore` is a system-wide service in Android that provides cryptographic operations and secure storage for keys. It's designed to securely generate and store cryptographic keys, and it's often used to protect data encryption keys rather than directly storing shared secrets or other sensitive data.

`EncryptedSharedPreferences`, on the other hand, is a wrapper around `SharedPreferences` that encrypts the keys and values before storing them. The encryption key used by `EncryptedSharedPreferences` is stored in `KeyStore`, which means the shared secret itself isn't stored directly in `KeyStore`, but it's encrypted using a key that is.

So, Using `EncryptedSharedPreferences` would be the recommended approach because it's specifically designed for this purpose. The encryption key used by `EncryptedSharedPreferences` is securely stored in `KeyStore`, providing an additional layer of security.

Here's a simple example of how you can use `EncryptedSharedPreferences`:

```java
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
    "secret_shared_prefs",
    masterKeyAlias,
    context,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
);

// use the shared preferences and editor as you normally would
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

I also recommend you to explore topic such as **Android’s Security library** and **Obfuscation**